# C remove printf output

Tags: c, console, printf

I would like to create a small function, which should show the current status in percentage in the console. The function should only show the current value in the line.
So I have to remove the last output. Is that possible? The best case would be some ANSI C stuff, the program should work on linux and windows.

I have found some escape sequences like `"\033[J"`, but it dose not work.

**Edit**

Well I tried it with:

```
void PrintProcessBar(int i, int n) {
    float ratio = i / (float)n;    
    printf("%.3d\b\b", (int)(ratio * 100));
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

But it just print lots of zeros... What went wrong? If I use three `\b` I get nothing.

**Solution**

```
float ratio = (i / (float)n) * 100;
printf("\b\b\b\b");
fflush(stdout);
printf("%.3d%c", (int)ratio, 37);        
fflush(stdout);
```

i = current position.
n = max runs.

I use 4 `\b` because, at the first call of the function it will remove 4 spaces.

Greetz.

Comment: Answers should be kept separate from the questions.  If you would like to answer your own question, you can do so by clicking the [Answer Your Question] button at the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`\b` is the escape sequence for backspace. you can use it with spaces to delete a line.

For example:

```
printf("98%");
fflush(stdout);
// sleep some time
printf("\b\b\b99%");
fflush(stdout);
```

This should print 98%, and then replace it with 99%.

Comment: Okay, I have tried it, but something went wrong. Please see my **Edit**. Thanks. Greetz.

Comment: You are printing three characters, but only return two each time, you probably need to return the same amount of the print (another \b should work).

Comment: I wrote that, if I use three `\b` `printf` will not print anything.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. How about writing it at the beginning of the next print?

Comment: Yea you are right! It dose not make sense to add it at the end... The output would remove it again! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

What you look for is `\r` it is Carriage Return. Makes the carriage go back to the beginning of the line. *Do not* use `\n` as it will go down one line.

Because \r does not delete text but simply allows you to overwrite, you have to make sure you print enough text (spaces if you need) to clear your line.

Comment: Oh, doesn't that depend on the system?

Comment: The endline depends on the system (`\n` for Linux and Mac, `\r\n` for windows, `\n\r` for "Acorn BBC and RISC OS spooled text output" and `\r` for Commodore 8-bit machines, Acorn BBC, TRS-80, Apple II family, Mac OS up to version 9 and OS-9 [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline))

Comment: So you'll have a problem doing \r on Mac OS up to 9

Comment: Hehe, for the development I use a Mac :).

Comment: If you have to be "MacOS < 10"-compliant then you should use `\b` as hinted in the answer of __Binyamin Sharet__. You're screwed with non-respect-of-the-standard-mac. For once it's not IE...